# Linearise equation. Solving for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

$$y = 2480.1 \times e^{-0.057 x}$$

Looking to get this equation in terms of x.
Thought it was ((log y)/log 2480.1))/(-0.057)=x
But not giving me answer expected  for x.
Thanks

Comment: your title is vague: it says linearize and solve. These are not same things.

Comment: I believe you want to solve for $x$ in terms of $y$. So instead of dividing by the log, think about log rules and "subtract".

Comment: Ok so (log y - log 2480.1)/-0.057 = x should Do it.

Comment: Thanks you anurag. Should have spotted.

Comment: Please, use MathJax

Answer (score 1):

Your question provides you with $y = 2480.1e^{−0.057x}$. Thus, step by step as follows, we have:
$$\frac{y}{2480.1} = e^{−0.057x}$$
$$ln({\frac{y}{2480.1}}) = −0.057x$$
$$x = -\frac{1}{0.057} \cdot ln({\frac{y}{2480.1}})$$